Getting AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
ViewModel not create instance when we make roomDB in module level (not in app level).
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 Process: documentreader.pdfreader.doc.pdf.reader.office, PID: 22010 java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.filereader.roomDb.FileItemViewModel
here is my view ViewModel class:
class FileItemViewModel(val application: Application,
                        val repository: FileItemRepository) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val allFileItems: LiveData<List<FileItem>> = repository.allFileItems
    fun insertIfNotExists(item: FileItem) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        Log.i("checkfav", "insertIfNotExists: enter ")
        val existingItem = repository.getFileItemByPath(item.filePath)
        if (existingItem == null) {
            Log.i("checkfav", "insertIfNotExists: existingItem ")
            repository.insert(item)
        } else {
            remove(existingItem)
        }
    }
    fun remove(item: FileItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.remove(item)
    }
    fun update(fileItem: FileItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.update(fileItem)
    }
}

This is how i create instance of my viewmodel class
var fileItemViewModel :FileItemViewModel? = null
activity?.let {
    fileItemViewModel = ViewModelProvider(it)[FileItemViewModel::class.java]
}

Thank you in advance for your assistance!
